# how to declare mongoose static methods that will work with ESLint

Tags: node.js, mongoose, eslint, mongoose-schema

Using Mongoose ORM for MongoDB

I've declared a mongoose static method like:

```js
ConvoDataSchema.statics.randomItem = async function () { ... }
```

and then create a model with that

```
const ConvoData = mongoose.model('ConvoData', ConvoDataSchema)
```

but later when I want to call the method:

```
let convoData = await ConvoData.randomItem()
```

My linter is not aware that `ConvoData` has had this magical method patched onto it by Mongoose.

How can I declare these methods such that a Linter (TSLint / VSCode Intellisense) can properly discover these methods?

Comment: I'm using `ESLint` and `VSCode`, it works properly for me.

Comment: it works on the line you're declaring it, but in other files does ESLint know about the `ConvoData.xx()` method declaration? I think ESLint can parse the inline syntax but not recognize the object it's attached to for exports.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that you could either tell ESLint to "ignore" lines like that, or you can get really weird and do something like:

```js
let convoData = await ConvoDataSchema.statics.randomItem.call(ConvoData)
```

Sucks that neither solution is as elegant as I'm sure you were hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the documentation I found this: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#statics

> Do not declare statics using ES6 arrow functions (=>). Arrow functions explicitly prevent binding **this**, so the above examples will not work because of the value of **this**."

Can be this your problem?

Comment: that might be a runtime issue. But the linter at compile time and intellisense can't really figure out those kind of issues. Maybe a true AST anaylsis linter could but i dont think ESLint is in that category.

Answer (score 0):

now I'm using typescript for most projects, and mongoose defeats getting decent intellisense because of some of the reasons above and more, my solution is not to use mongoose...

Answer (score -1):

If declared exactly like this:

```
ConvoDataSchema.statics.randomItem = async function () {
const ConvoData = mongoose.model('ConvoData', ConvoDataSchema)
```

it won't work because the method wasn't closed. You should try closing the method.
Further, what exactly is the method returning, that way, we can properly debug the method.

Comment: this was just a snippet of the source. I've made it more clear above.